# flutter:: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a function where the recorded voice is displayed on the screen when recording.
However, if there is no record(null) in the widget, the above error occurs because length cannot be used. How can I solve this?

```
class Record extends StatefulWidget {
  const Record({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  get records => null;


  @override
  _RecordState createState() => _RecordState();
}

class _RecordState extends State<Record> {
  late int _totalTime;
  late int _currentTime;
  double _percent = 0.0;
  int _selected = -1;
  bool isPlay=false;
  AudioPlayer advancedPlayer = AudioPlayer();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.records.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      reverse: true,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
        return Card(
          elevation: 5,
          child: ExpansionTile(
            title: Text(
              'Record ${widget.records.length - i}',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't return the `ListView.builder` if the `records` is null.

```dart
return widget.records == null ? SizedBox() : ListView.builder...
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your class like this,

```dart
class Record extends StatefulWidget {
  const Record({
    Key? key,
    required this.records,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List records;

  @override
  _RecordState createState() => _RecordState();
}
```

In the above code `records` is a list of type `List<dynamic>`. If you have a specific data type,

```dart
final List<YOUR_DATA_TYPE> records;
```

This way, records will never be null. If `records` can be null,

```dart
final List<YOUR_DATA_TYPE>? records;
```

and use,

```dart
return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.records?.length ?? 0,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      reverse: true,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
        return Card(
          elevation: 5,
          child: ExpansionTile(
            title: Text(
              'Record ${widget.records.length - i}',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

jiji.!

It return null because in some case, Listview execute before assign value to the `widget.records` in build. In that case you may get null list even there is records in `widget.records`.

So, you just need to handle this null exception. Like,

```
ListView.builder(
shrinkWrap: true,
reverse: true,
physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
itemCount: widget.records.length,
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
    widget.customer == null
        ? Card(
            elevation: 5,
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'No Records Found',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 14,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        : widget.records.isEmpty
            ? Card(
                elevation: 5,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'No Records Available',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 14,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : Card(
                elevation: 5,
                child: ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'Record ${widget.records.length - index}',
                    style:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
),
```

It will check for **NULL, Empty List** and **With Records** list.